# Can not initialize struct inside a struct-C2224 Error

Tags: c

I am trying to initialize a string in C on this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

struct person{
    char name[10];
    int id;
}; typedef person_t;

struct family{
    person_t father;
    person_t mother;
    person_t kid[10];
}; typedef family_t;

void main()
{
     family_t fam;
     fam.father.name = "sdsd";
}
```

This code gives me C-2224 Eror.
How do i access eache struct of type person_t that are inside the struct of type family_t?

Comment: The problem isn't about struct within a struct, but that you can't assign to an array, only [copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) to it.

Comment: `fam.father.name = "sdsd";`-> `strcpy(fam.father.name, "sdsd");`

Comment: yahh if find that there were to many ; in the struct.